Could a Tool Like ChartDB Work for MongoDB Schema Visualization?
I’m one of the developers behind ChartDB, an open-source tool for database schema visualization, particularly useful for relational databases (RDBMS). Our tool helps users generate ER diagrams to map out relationships between tables with ease.
We’re exploring the idea of adapting ChartDB for MongoDB, but we’re facing unique challenges due to MongoDB’s document-oriented, hierarchical data structure. Given this structure is fundamentally different from the flat, tabular schema of RDBMS, I’d love to hear the community's thoughts on a few points:

Would a schema visualization tool be helpful for MongoDB users, and
if so, what aspects of the document structure would be most valuable
to visualize?
What key features should such a tool include to be
genuinely useful for MongoDB data modeling?
Are there any existing
approaches or tools in the MongoDB ecosystem that we should look at
as reference points?

If you have any experience or thoughts on the matter, your insights would be highly valuable as we consider expanding ChartDB’s functionality to support MongoDB.
Thanks in advance! You can also check out the project on GitHub.

In MongoDB the schema is typically designed and ensured on the application layer rather than on the database. Thus, it depends in which programming language you developed your application. I think for most of the popular programming language you should find a visualization tool.

If there is an array inside an object that's a one-to-many relationship. One could build an ER diagram accordingly. A logical data model is different to a physical DB design. The tool could be useful in this context. Whether it would be used, however, ...
